# EJB @Stateless bean with two clients on different methods and poolsize = 1

Tags: java, ejb, stateless

Please help me understand @Stateless EJB 3 beans.

If I have a bean with two methods and pool size 1, could two clients have simultaneous access to this bean provided that they call different methods on it.

I feel that answer is "no" since ejb does not check whether methods are not linked internally. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no because the spec guarantees that a given EJB instance is never called concurrently.